# An image to be displayed inline in a JavaMail created message shows up twice in Apple Mail – but not Outlook?

Tags: jakarta-mail

An image to be displayed inline in a JavaMail created message shows up twice in Apple Mail – but not Outlook?

EmailMaster sends a test email message that includes: 
1) an image sent with the email to be displayed inline in the title when the message is opened
2) a link to an image that has to be downloaded from a remote URL after the message is displayed.

The goal is for the message to be fully rendered when it is opened (owl).  Not require the reader download it before seeing full message.

The code below works perfectly when the message is opened in a client like Outlook.
-- the Owl image displayed in line when its opened, and
-- the underline must be downloaded.

When AppleMail opens the message the Owl is displayed twice.  The screen show:
-- the owl as a standalone image,
-- then the message with the owl correctly displayed in the Title.

I can’t post a screen shot, but I put a screen shot of the AppleMail screen at
http://america-3.org/images/shot.jpg

Can anyone point me to the cause of the problem?  Or a solution?

HTML code added as one MimeBodyPart.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link href="cid:fonts" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css"> 
    <!--
      .text-blue-12 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                     text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; 
                     font-size:12pt; color: #0F0F0F}
       body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #1A4576; width: 480px;} 
       tr {width:100%;  background-color: white;}
     --> 
     </style>     
  </head>
  <body>
      <table width='480px' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='6' class='text-blue-12' align="center">
        <tr><td style='text-align: center;'>
            Hello! <img src='cid:owl'>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align: center;'>
          <img align="center" alt="Shadow" class="kmImage"
               src="https://d3k81ch9hvuctc.cloudfront.net/assets/email/bottom_shadow_444.png"
               width="600" style="border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%;
               outline:none; text-decoration: none; max-width: 100%; padding-bottom: 0; 
               display: inline; vertical-align: bottom" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
          This is test # 1005.  The Table should be a 480px wide and centered.
          If not there is a problem.
        </td></tr>
      <tr><td>
        Yours truly,
        GLB
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Extract of Java Class I use to test JavaMail code

```
public class EmailMaster {
  /* JavaMail attempts to use IPv6 to  connect. Windows IPv4.  
   * The error message will be "Network Unreachable: Connect.
   * To fix it, I ran this code from the command window 
   * setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   * I tried to set _JAVA_OPTIONS as an environment variable but that didn't
   * work.
   */

/* the constructor instantiates EmailMaster. 
 * It parses a ".properties" text file that provides the everything 
 * needed to define a message:
 * -- send from, reply to, subject etc. Strings
 * -- local paths to one or more files:
 *      .. a text file containing the to addresses.
 *      .. the HTML file that holds the message body,
 *      .. one of more images to be displayed inline
 *         in the HTML message body.  I used one.
 *      .. one or more files to be attached to the msg. I used one.
 */ 

/* then it calls sendEmail() to read through the list of addresses 
 * and sends an individual email to each address*/

sendEmail () {
  /*this section of code is done once. */
  Session session = Session.getInstance(this.sessionParameters);
  SMTPTransport tr = new SMTPTransport(session, new URLName (host));
  tr.connect(...); // this is successful

  /* the method loops through this section for every to address provided*/
  Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
  msg.setReplyTo(this.replyToAddress);// read from properties file
  msg.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());// read from properties file
  msg.setSubject(this.subject);// read from properties file
  msg.setFrom(this.fromAddress);// read from properties file
  msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, singleToAddress);// read from properties file

  MimeMultipart mmp = new MimeMultipart();

  /* add a MimeBodyPart for each image be displayed inline the HTML text */
  for (MimeBodyPart part : this.imagesBodyParts.values()) {
    mmp.addBodyPart(part);
    /* add a MimeBodyPart for each HTML page in the message. */
    for (MimeBodyPart part : this.attachmentBodyParts.values()) {
      mmp.addBodyPart(part);
    }
    mmp.addBodyPart(this.msgPart);
    msg.setContent(mmp);
    msg.saveChanges();
    tr.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit to how much control you have over how mail readers display messages.  In the end, you may not be able to accomplish what you're trying to do with all mail readers.  That said, there's some issues with the code you posted...

You've got a double nested "for" loop that first adds an image body part, then adds a bunch of attachment (html?) body parts, then sends the message, then adds more of both to the same message, then sends the message again, and so on.  Surely this isn't what you intended.

If you want the message to include a single html part and some image parts that are referenced by the html part, you need to create a multipart/related message, and the image parts need Content-ID headers.  [This JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr) will point you in the right direction.

Finally, you should never be calling the constructor for SMTPTransport directly.  Instead, you should use the Session.getTransport method.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I had the double nest (i.e. the 1st msg went to the 1st address, 2nd msg to the 1st and 2nd, 3rd msg to the 1st, 2nd, and third address, etc. into chaos.  But I fixed that so I must have screwed up the extract I posted.  As for the the other advice I'll need to read more, and come back in a  few days.  I'm still trying to get a grip on JavaMail. When I get it working I'll post the working code.  Thanks again.